# ASP.NET Core wildcard route except

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using ASP.NET Core to serve an SPA like this:

```
[<Route("{*url}")>]
member this.Index () =      
    this.View("~/wwwroot/Index.cshtml")
```

My JSON endpoints are on the same app, routed like this:

```
[<Route("api/something/{somethingId:int})>]
```

This works fine, except that when I try to call an endpoint `api/something/that/doesnt/exist` I get the index page when I actually want a 404.

Is it possible to setup `[<Route("{*url}")>]` in such a way that it excludes any url that starts with "api"?

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39517816/how-to-ignore-routes-in-asp-net-core-1-0-1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use [Route Constraints](http://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/06/25/route-constraints-asp-net-core/). There is a regex option which you can use to filter out the API calls (That you don't want).

You then need to do a negative lookahead to negate a string.

```
[<Route("{*url:regex(^(?!api).*$)}")>]
```