# Ignoring Request in middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, react-router-v4, reactjs.net

So I want IIS to basically not do anything when certain urls are requested bacause I want react router to which I have rendered from serverside, to handle the request.

Used this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39517816/how-to-ignore-routes-in-asp-net-core-1-0-1)

I have created a middleware that checks each request. Now i dont know how to ignore or abort this request once I find the right urls.

```
public class IgnoreRouteMiddleware
{

    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    // You can inject a dependency here that gives you access
    // to your ignored route configuration.
    public IgnoreRouteMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.HasValue &&
            context.Request.Path.Value!="/")
        {


           // cant stop anything here. Want to abort to ignore this request

        }

        await next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to stop a request, just don't call `next.Invoke(context)`, because this will call the next middleware in the pipeline. Not calling it, just ends the request (and the previous middlewares code after it's `next.Invoke(context)` will be processed).

In your case, just move the call to the else branch or just negate the if expression

```
public class IgnoreRouteMiddleware
{

    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    // You can inject a dependency here that gives you access
    // to your ignored route configuration.
    public IgnoreRouteMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!(context.Request.Path.HasValue && context.Request.Path.Value!="/"))
        {
            await next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Also make sure to read the [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware?tabs=aspnetcore2x) documentation for a better understanding on how middlewares work.

> Middleware is software that is assembled into an application pipeline to handle requests and responses. Each component:
>
> - Chooses whether to pass the request to the next component in the pipeline.
> - **Can perform work before and after the next component in the pipeline is invoked**.

But if you want server-sided rendering, consider using Microsoft`s [JavaScript/SpaServices](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) library, which is already built in in the newer templates (ASP.NET Core 2.0.x) and register a fallback route such as.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
        name: "spa-fallback",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
});
```

The new templates also come with support for hot module replacement