# Azure multiple sites in virtual directories

Tags: azure, ssl, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, virtual-directory

I have 3 asp.net core sites I need to deploy on the same domain (subdomains will not work with my SSL certificate).

- https://my-site.com (Single page app)
- https://my-site.com/api (Web api)
- https://my-site.com/identity (Identity server)

[image: virtual-directories-config]

When I deploy the api and identity projects, they work fine. However, when deploying the single page app, api and identity stop working.

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

The error appears instantly so it's probably failing early on from startup I guess.
The single page app is working ok.

It seems the spa is interfering, I tried solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39517816/how-to-ignore-routes-in-asp-net-core-1-0-1) to ignore the routes, but I get the same error.

I have tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43669437/1875786) to get a more descriptive error but to no avail.

Not sure where to go from here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the problem is that both the root application and the child app add the `aspNetCore` handler, causing the config system to blow up. You can see this by turning on *Detailed error messages* in the Azure Portal, and then finding the error page under `D:\home\LogFiles\DetailedErrors`. You'll see this error:

> Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'aspNetCore'

There are two approaches to solving this.

The first is to use a `location` tag to prevent inheritance. Specifically, change your root app's `web.config` from something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\myapp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

to something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\myapp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

The second approach is to remove the `<handlers>` section from the *sub*-application to avoid the duplication (as suggested in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x) under *Configuration of sub-applications*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\mySubApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```